# Has Yoda ever flown a starfighter?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, yoda

In the films, we've seen Yoda fly in military transports and escape pods, but has he ever flown a starfighter? Most Jedi do, and he's one of the oldest of them all. I would imagine he has in his youth, but his early days have barely been chronicled yet.  Is there any mention of this in any EU material? Legends or Disney canon accepted.